# Is there a way to achieve different flex-box layouts with one parent and three children?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a way to achieve the below layout for small/large screens by using flex-box with just one parent and three children?

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="green"></div>
   <div class="pink"></div>
   <div class="violet"></div>
</div>

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.green {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-colour: lightgreen;
}

.pink {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-colour: pink;
}

.violet {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-colour: violet;
}
```

[image: Small layout]

[image: Large layout]

The code above works for the small layout. For the large layout however, all I can think about is doing it the old school way by using float, which feels like an ugly work around rather than the actual solution.

```
.parent {
  display: block;
}

.green {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-colour: lightgreen;
  float: left
}

.pink {
  margin-left: 10rem;
  background-colour: pink;
}

.violet {
  margin-left: 10rem;
  background-colour: violet;
}
```

Comment: Flexbox basically works in one "main direction." You should look into _grid_ instead of flexbox.

Comment: This looks like it'd be better off as a `grid`.

Comment: No. Neither flexbox or Css-grid can simply achieve the second image. You do not have a row in that image.

Comment: Not true @Paulie_D, css-grid solved it perfectly fine, exactly like in the images. See below answer. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @ somethinghere and @ CBroe

Comment: Nope. That answer makes the green area two rows high, not the same as the image.

Comment: @Paulie_D yes you're right actually. Sorry! I can still achieve the layout by simply letting the green area be the placeholder and place the content with fixed height inside of it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like `grid` is the solution, not `flexbox`:

```
.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 10rem auto;
    grid-template-areas:
        'green pink'
        'violet violet';

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        grid-template-columns: 25rem auto;
        grid-template-areas:
            'green pink'
            'green violet';
    }
}

.green { // will span over 2 rows but can be used as the placeholder for the item with fixed height/width
    background-color: lightgreen;
    grid-area: green;
}

.pink {
    background-color: pink;
    grid-area: pink;
}

.violet {
    background-color: violet;
    grid-area: violet;
}
```